# How to fix the problem in the awk script?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have the following dataset obtained using bcftools;

```
$ bcftools query -f '%CHROM %POS %REF %ALT %AN %AC \n' fname.vcf
```

```
CHROM POS REF ALT AN AC 

6 85406127 T A 6 2
6 85406180 T G 6 5
6 85406187 T G 6 1
-
-
-
6 85434019 T A 0 0
6 85434075 A C 0 0
```

The desired output is obtained by the following command:

```
bcftools query -f '%CHROM %POS %REF %ALT %AN %AC \n' fname.vcf | awk '$5 !=0' | awk '{printf "%s:%s %s:%s %f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4,$6/$5}'
```

```
6:85406127 T:A 0.333333
6:85406139 T:C 0.000000
6:85406180 T:G 0.833333
```

In the dataset, it contains zero's in the 5th and 6th columns. So 0 divided by 0 results in **fatal: division by zero attempted**. That's why I want to see NAs in the third column of the output.

```
6:85406127 T:A 0.333333
6:85406139 T:C NA
6:85406180 T:G 0.833333
```

My attempt to obtain the output was shown below:

```
bcftools query -f '%CHROM %POS %REF %ALT %AN %AC \n' fname.vcf | awk '{ if [[ $5!= 0 && $6!=0 ]]
'{printf "%s:%s %s:%s %f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4,$6/$5}'
else
'{printf "%s:%s %s:%s %b\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, 'NA'}'
}'
```

But I received this result:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: { if [[ $5!= 0 && $6!=0 ]]
awk: cmd. line:1:      ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { if [[ $5!= 0 && $6!=0 ]]
awk: cmd. line:1:                         ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:2: {printf
awk: cmd. line:2:        ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

How can I fix this issue?

Any contribution is welcomed!

Comment: You're trying to use shell syntax within awk. awk and shell are 2 completely different tools, each with their own syntax and semantics. awk's syntax is far more similar to C than it is to shell.

Comment: Where did `85406139` come from?  It’s in the output but not the input.  And where did ``85434019`` and ``85434075`` go?  They’re in the input but not the output.  Please post data that ***illustrate*** your question.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in my question. The numbers are very similar to the numbers in my dataset. But they are just random numbers. I think your question is out of the context of what I am looking for. The answers already helped to fix my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. Use this awk:

`awk '{ if ($5!= 0 && $6!= 0) {printf "%s:%s %s:%s %f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4,$6/$5} else {printf "%s:%s %s:%s NA\n", $1, $2, $3, $4} }'`

The 'NA' string is part of the `printf` string itself. Also, you do not put the `{ *statemet* }` inside `'`

Also, do not mix `bash` calculations (`[[  ]]`) inside AWK.

You can have a quick check of the AWK grammar [here](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-13)

Comment: The `'NA'` string is in awk, and needs to be `"NA"`. Also, I don't understand your first "divide by zero" issue: if you already eliminated rows using `$5 != 0`, then where did the zero divide come from?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, the second script in the question does not contain the initial `$5 !=0`

Comment: Thanks ferranm I am very new in using awk commands. Your suggestion is very helpful!  @Paul_Pedant if I don't use  $5 != 0, I get an error due to divide by zero" issue. But I want to keep these rows as NA. ferranm's suggestion helped me to fix it.

Comment: @ferranm The first example script does show `awk '$5 !=0'`, as a separate stage in the pipeline. After that, we get division by zero mentioned as a problem. We also see a header line that the code does not ignore but also does not appear in the output. Then we get another script that throws syntax everywhere. It could have been made clearer.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a ternary expression:

```
bcf... | awk 'NR>1{printf "%s:%s %s:%s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, ($5 ? $6/$5 : "NA")}'
```

It doesn't matter if `$6` is `0` or not since you aren't dividing by it.

Look (using `cat file` in place of your `bcf...` command which I don't have):

```
$ cat file
CHROM POS REF ALT AN AC
6 85406127 T A 6 2
6 85406180 T G 6 5
6 85406187 T G 6 1
6 85434019 T A 0 0
6 85434075 A C 0 0

$ cat file | awk 'NR>1{printf "%s:%s %s:%s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, ($5 ? $6/$5 : "NA")}'
6:85406127 T:A 0.333333
6:85406180 T:G 0.833333
6:85406187 T:G 0.166667
6:85434019 T:A NA
6:85434075 A:C NA
```